# How to mark or highlight code sections in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am studying a large project, and would like to mark already studied and understood code sections (preferably in color).
Is there such possibility in Visual Studio itself or is there a plugin with such functionality? Similar functionality is available in Notepad++ and is called "Style token". But there the selected areas are not saved when you close the file. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the #region directive to mark blocks of code. This will not affect the color though. For example :

#region IUnderstoodThisSection

code

#endregion